# Flutter TextFormField reloads whole app when focused or clicked for editing

Tags: flutter, forms, flutter-textformfield

I am using TextFormField When I focus on it. It reloads my whole application from start. The keyboard does appear. But it starts from the start of the application from the main page. I am unable to share the whole project. I am running this code on Android devices only. I have tried few solutions from this plateform but these are not working for me.

```
class _GuideRequestState extends State<GuideRequest> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> mylist = [];
  String? selectedCity;
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Future<List<dynamic>?> fetchCity() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(uri + '/api/getd/City'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
        // then parse the JSON.
        final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> innerList = [];
        for (var x in parsed) {
          var keys = x.keys.toList();
          innerList.add({"id": x['id'], "name": x['Name']});
        }
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            mylist = innerList;
          });
          print("List is this: " + mylist.toString());
        }
        print(Navigator);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("In Guide Error: " + e.toString());
    }
    return mylist;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchCity();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Become a Guide',
                  style: GoogleFonts.pacifico(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    underline: Container(
                      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side:
                              BorderSide(width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    hint: selectedCity == null
                        ? Text('Select City')
                        : Text(selectedCity!),
                    items: mylist.map((x) => x['name']).map((x) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Text(x),
                        value: x,
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedCity = value as String?;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Form(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.phone_android,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                              hintText: 'Phone Number',
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter usually reloads the page when textfield is clicked because of the keyboard adjustment.
Furthermore, I faced same issue. I was creating variables into build widget. Try to look into the project and find if somewhere you're creating variable into build widget.

Comment: dhanywad nukile bhai sab